# The difference between slick and sleek

Tags: differences, adjectives, synonyms

What is the difference between the two adjectives: *slick* and *sleek*?
My dictionary returns almost the same explanation for both, like *smooth* and *glossy*.

Could someone explain when it would be more appropriate to use one or the other.
Thank you.

Comment: _Slick_ is a pejorative term, but _sleek_ need not be. Otherwise they're pretty similar; obviously one is a variant of the other. [They're not the only words in this boat](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sl.pdf), though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both mean smooth or seeming to be smooth.

To me, *slick* is more about **touch**: slippery, and sleek is more about **sight**/appearance. A wet moss-covered surface is slick. A satin skirt is sleek.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. _Sleek_ does seem to require vision, while _slick_ is much more about tactile and balance sensations. _Sleek curves_ is quite visual, whereas _slick curves_ is either a metaphoric compliment or a reference to slipperiness.

Answer (score 2):

As a metaphorical descriptive, "slick" implies "sexy" (also in the metaphorical sense), and, as with real sex, what is considered "sexy" varies greatly from one observer and context to the next.  I might consider a 20 pound bicycle to be "slick", while someone else would apply the adjective to a 1000 pound motorcycle.  But the term, absent knowledge of the observer's preferences, implies nothing about the form of the object.

See [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=slick):

> ```
> slick
>   Smooth, cool, awesome. 
>   Luke is so slick
> ```

"Sleek", on the other hand, is somewhat more objective, though it may also be metaphorical.  It refers to the shape and form of the entity, and means, basically, "streamlined" or "smooth and flowing".  A fancy sports car will generally be considered "sleek".

Comment: Is your view that _slick_ implies "sexy" based on any authority? No dictionary I know of shows even a hint of such a meaning for _slick_.

Comment: @JK2: If you do a Google Images search for "slick", the very first image is of the Fonz from Happy Days. What more evidence do you need? ;-)

Comment: I'd say "slick" means more "clever and graceful" than "sexy", but freely admit the overlap is great.