# The car is pretty slick/sleek

Tags: differences, adjectives, synonyms

At [1:35 into this clip](https://youtu.be/B5goHV7tFnE?t=1m35s) of the animation movie 'Despicable Me 3', Dru shows his twin brother, Gru, their dad's supercar:

> Dru: *Dad's villain wheels. Pretty slick, huh?*

According to this previous question about [the difference between slick and sleek](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171178/the-difference-between-slick-and-sleek), John Lawler says in a comment:

> *Slick* is a pejorative term, but *sleek* need not be.

And the only answer having 9 votes says:

> To me, slick is more about touch: slippery, and sleek is more about sight/appearance. A wet moss-covered surface is slick. A satin skirt is sleek.

To which John Lawler agrees.

As far as I know, Dru wasn't portraying his dad's car in a negative way at all. Also, it's all about "sight/appearance" and not really about "touch".

Then, why is *slick* used instead of *sleek* here?

Comment: "Slick" is not (necessarily) pejorative.  Context is everything.

Comment: @HotLicks Please elaborate on how context translates into using _slick_ instead of _sleek_ in this movie clip.

Comment: In most contexts "That's a pretty slick car" would be a compliment.  But "You have your pants on backwards, Slick" uses the term in a pejorative fashion.  And there's a significant difference between the meaning of "slick" (in the non-pejorative sense) and "sleek".

Comment: @HotLicks So the distinction made in the previous comment/answer is useless? Also, would you use 'slick' or 'sleek' in this 'car' context?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/422760/70861

Comment: @HotLicks Your answer to that question only makes the use of 'slick' instead of 'sleek' in this movie all the more strange.

Comment: How so?  How would "Pretty sexy, huh?" be considered strange?

Comment: @HotLicks Because you say "A fancy sports car will generally be considered _sleek_,"

Comment: A fancy sports car is streamlined.

Comment: While we are on the topic of cars, I should point out that **Slick** is also a type of tyre. And as the word suggests, Slick tyres are smooth and have no treads. **Sleek** tyres on the other hand don't have to be smooth, just good-looking :)

Comment: In this case *slick* is not being used literally, but as a positive adjective loosely connected to its original meaning. Like *cool*, *radical*, *wicked*, *fresh*, *neat*, *clean*, *tight*, *bangin*, *bananas*, *stylin*, etc.

Comment: You should look the words up in a reputable, professionally compiled dictionary instead of sourcing either *comments* or answers (such as @Drew's) that don't cite such a dictionary.

Answer (score 26):

*Slick*, when it is used metaphorically instead of literally, simply means "cool" or "neat" or "clever", as shown by these definitions:

> 3 a : characterized by subtlety or nimble wit : clever; especially : wily • *a slick swindler*
>   b : deft, skillful • *a slick ballplayer*
>   4 : extremely good : first-rate
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slick)*</sub>

As you can see, there's nothing pejorative about it when used in this sense.

"Slick" can refer to the car's coolness factor; it covers how good it looks, 
how well it works, and how much nifty stuff it can do.

"Sleek" can only refer to the car's appearance.

Comment: And now I will start using *sleek* to mean *cool* or *awesome*. Just because it sounds totally sleek.

Answer (score 6):

Per the *OED*, **slick** and **sleek** as *adjectives* both share a quite similar meaning, having both derived from Middle English *slike*, meaning essentially "smooth."

The pejorative nature of "slick" is much more recent and manifests in a slang *noun* form first attested as recently as **1959**.

> *U.S. slang.* A clever or smart person; **a cheat or swindler**. [emphasis mine]

This sense is cross-referenced to *slicker* and *slickster*, which means essentially "swindler."  It is likely a figurative outgrowth of the earlier U.S. sense meaning "slippery."

The sense you refer to in the movie is more likely *OED* *adjective* definition **5**.

> First-class, excellent; neat, in good order; smart, efficient, that operates smoothly; superficially attractive, glibly clever. (Of things, actions, etc.)

This sense is first attested in **1833** making it also quite recent relative to more *literal* sense of the word *slick*, as in "smooth."  Unlike the slang sense referenced first, there is nothing *necessarily* pejorative about this sense, though it is worth noting the second portion of the definition, "superficially attractive."  This is where context comes in.  In the context of a person referring to their own car as **slick**, it is unlikely that they meant "superficially attractive;" rather they likely meant "first-class, excellent."

Answer (score 5):

- *Slick* is originally a tactile term, meaning slippery, like ice.
- *Sleek*, on the other hand, is more visual, meaning smooth-looking, like oiled skin.

The initial *sl-* in both cases is not accidental.

[The `SL-` assonance in English](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/sl.pdf) has the basic sense of two-dimensional contact at a liquid-solid interface. Since events like this are rarely pleasant for humans (think of slipping in the slush and slopping home), there is also a sizable number of pejorative terms with `SL-`.
In fact, there is a large phonosemantic overlap among the 74 English simplex words with the `SL-` assonance.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't even matter which you use in the context of this movie?

Comment: If we're talking about expression of extreme teen-age approval, either one could surface. There's no predicting slang.

Answer (score 3):

Slick might also be used in a fancy term. To call something slick could mean that the person thinks its extra cool or rad. if you use sleek it would sound to the person that it means clean or collected.

Comment: Would you use 'slick' or 'sleek' in the 'car context?

Comment: @JK2 - a [T-bucket hot rod](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/T-Bucket.jpg) would hardly be considered "sleek", but many admirers would call it "slick".